webots, 4 wheel robot's heading angle by Rotation field
I'm using Webots R2023b.
I created a 4-wheeled robot following the tutorials (https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-6-4-wheels-robot).
However, I'm having difficulty obtaining the heading angle of the robot.
There are two robots in my world, and Robot 2 needs Robot 1's heading angle.
Initially, I attempted to use sensor. This failed because Robot 2's controller(supervisor) cannot access Robot 1's sensor directly.
Then, I tried retrieving the rotation field value of Robot 1 (which was accessible by Robot 2). Unfortunately, the rotation field value seems inaccurate (possibly too precise).
The Rotation Field looks something like this:
x: 0.192133
y: -0.981369
z: 1.16056e-05
angle: 0.00000629627
This information isn't sufficient to determine a proper angle value. Particularly, the direction of the angular velocity is unclear because the Z value continuously fluctuates between positive and negative values.
I suspect this might be due to physics simulations, but I'm not sure.
In summary, "Robot 2's controller needs Robot 1's heading angle".
Any suggestions on how to achieve this?
I appreciate your help in advance.
